# Configure plugin in separate file using Kotlin DSL

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

to differenciate diferent plugins configurations, I use separate files.

For example:

> ./build.gradle.kts
>   **./detekt.gradle.kts**
>   ./settings.gradle.kts
>   ./module1
>   ./module2
>   ...

In the root `build.gradle.kts` I have this:

```
plugins {
    id("io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt") version DependencyVersion.Detekt
}

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath(io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt:detekt-gradle-plugin:1.1.1)
    }
}
```

And to configure it I go to the `detekt.gradle.kts` and put:

```
apply(plugin = "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")

detekt {
    // configure
}
```

But `detekt` lambda is not found. Also tried with:

```
apply(plugin = "io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt")

configure<io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.Detekt> {
    // configure
}
```

But it doesn't find `.Detekt`.

With JaCoCo I haven't got any problems using the second approach, but it doesn't work with Detekt or SonarQube.

How can I configure plugins in a separate file?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey @alinex, did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below. I have declared a plugin "sonarqube" in my main gradle. I then apply the file sonar.gradle.kts towards the end of the build.gradle.kts file.

```
    build.gradle.kts:
    plugins {
      id("org.sonarqube") version "2.8" apply false
    }
    ...

    apply(from="$rootDir/gradle/includes/sonar.gradle.kts")    

    gradle/includes/sonar.gradle.kts:
    apply(plugin="org.sonarqube")
```

Using a setup like above, I can then run "gradle sonarqube"

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. Everything that you need to do is to call

```
configure<io.gitlab.arturbosch.detekt.extensions.DetektExtension> {             
    // configure
}
```

More info, you can find here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/migrating_from_groovy_to_kotlin_dsl.html#configuring-plugins